# job queue with multiple consumers did the same job twice

Tags: postgresql

Actually a lot of things might be covered here: [Job queue as SQL table with multiple consumers (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507475/job-queue-as-sql-table-with-multiple-consumers-postgresql)

However I just wanted to ask for my specific query.

Currently I have a job queue that actually should emit a new job for every consumer, however we found out that we sometimes gotten the same job twice on different consumer (probably a race condition.
This was our query (run inside a transaction):

```
UPDATE invoice_job SET status = 'working', date_time_start = now(), 
node = $ip 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM invoice_job WHERE status = 'created' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
RETURNING *
```

Currently the Table is pretty simple and has a status (can be "created", "working", "done", date_time_start field, created field (not used for query), id field, node (where the job was run).

However this emitted the same job twice at one point.
Currently I changed the query now to:

```
UPDATE invoice_job SET status = 'working', date_time_start = now(), 
node = $ip 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM invoice_job WHERE status = 'created' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)
RETURNING *
```

would that actually help and only emit the same job once?

Comment: yes - for update should lock the row. here is another fresh reading if curious https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Comment: A more traditional approach would be to include your status-condition in the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause too, i.e. `WHERE id = (...) AND status = 'created'`. But `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is actually a more "clever" solution, when you can use it.

Comment: what means "if you can use it?"

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt some ORMs/DBALs might limit, what you can execute & `SKIP LOCKED` is not standard SQL. `FOR UPDATE` is neither standard (at least, in plain `SELECT`s), but it is a usual extension. -- *Although FOR UPDATE appears in the SQL standard, the standard allows it only as an option of DECLARE CURSOR. PostgreSQL allows it in any SELECT query as well as in sub-SELECTs, but this is an extension.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution with `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is fine. It'll ensure a row is locked by exactly one session before being updated for processing. No transaction can choose a row already locked by another transaction, and when the lock is released on commit, subsequent `SELECT` clauses will no longer match the row.

The original failed because the subquery's `SELECT` can choose the same row concurrently in multiple sessions, each of which then tries to `UPDATE` the row. There's no `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` that'd make that fail; it's perectly fine for two concurrent sessions to `UPDATE invoice_job SET status = 'working' WHERE node = 42` or whatever. The second update will happily run and commit once the first update succeeds.

You could also make it safe by repeating the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE invoice_job SET status = 'working', date_time_start = now(), 
node = $ip 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM invoice_job WHERE status = 'created' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
  AND status = 'created'
RETURNING *
```

... but this will often return zero rows under high concurrency.

In fact it will return zero rows for all but one of a set of concurrent executions, so it's no better than a serial queue worker. This is true of most of the other "clever" tricks people use to try to do concurrent queues, and one of the main reasons `SKIP LOCKED` was introduced.

The fact that you only noticed this problem now tells me that you would actually be fine with a simple, serial queue dispatch where you `LOCK TABLE` before picking the first row. But `SKIP LOCKED` will scale better if your workload grows.